# I'm not banned yet the "Post Your Question" button is not working

Tags: support

As far as I am aware, I have not been banned as the page redirect upon posting does not show that. In addition I have only asked one question that was up voted!

Despite this, as I am typing the question, the preview area beneath the posting box doesn't show anything, and the **Post Your Question** button does not respond to mouse click at all! What has happened?!

Comment: what was the page redirect??

Comment: FYI: The post ban also counts deleted posts. Do you have a lot of those that received low scores before being deleted?

Comment: there is no page redirect. the post box is not following my type as I write and the post question button is inactive

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors?

Comment: @Doorknob I am so JEALOUS, SO SO SOS jealous, I was looking for a tag equivalent of markdown preview, you are, seriously, the cleverest doorknob I've ever known

Comment: none! thus my confusion, and I have checked that others are posting as we speak so it seems to be either my account or the browser. I have checked my account and nothing seems to be wrong but as a newbie I do not know what to look for

Comment: @Yve err... I just typed "preview" into the tags and that's what it suggested :P Also, there aren't really many clever doorknobs out there :P

Comment: i dont believe my account has any deleted posts. i have restarted the computer since the problem came up yesterday and my account name is the same there as here if that helps?

Comment: You said "as the page redirect upon posting does not show that", but then you said "clicking 'post question' does not respond at all". How did you get to the page redirect in the first place?

Comment: there was no page redirect, I was simply trying to say that nothing indicated a  ban from research I did of what happens when banned.

Comment: this post 'Preview and tag suggestions broken when creating a new post [closed]' is the only other that has a similar issue that I have found.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this problem myself by deleting the cache in my browser. Works fine now!

Comment: Only you can accept an answer. Glad it helper.

Comment: you got upvotes for posting a question and answer the sole basis of which, was clearing your browser cache?? O M G seriously ??

Comment: @Yve They solved their own problem, and posted the solution. That's a good thing, why shouldn't it be worth some upvotes?

Comment: omg, it's a programming site, clearing browser cache is a step up from knowing how to turn on the computer.. there are plenty of questions, that involve skill that get rejected (and should be).. in this case.. I, honestly, think it's ridiculous

Comment: @Yve _This_ is the meta site, where everything is about the site's mechanism and usage. And if clearing the cache solves a problem that at first hand doesn't seem trivial, others will benefit from the answer as well...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler a man convinced against his will is of the same opinion still.... Can I have my opinion, does it make it wrong for me to think this and to disagree with you? Are you sure you are right and I am wrong? Am I allowed to think that anyone with an interest in programming would have the rudimentary skills needed to use a pc and the internet?? How is this logic flawed?? Hm?

Comment: @Yve Nah, everyone's free to have their opinion. And indeed for this question there's no right or wrong, just opinion. Either one trying to convince the other would just waste time

Comment: @TobiasKienzler that is all I wanted to hear, it is the differences in opinions that make up the whole and, as a community, we achieve some form of equilibrium.

Comment: @Yve Equilibrium is boring - equilibrium is the entire universe converted into iron...